# How can I write simple Lua code for Logitech mouse?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to make a script for logitech mouse that:

1. When left mouse button is pressed, it will activate case 1
2. When holding the right mouse button and pressing the left mouse button, it will activate the case 2

However, no matter how I try it will only work on case 1.

```lua
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
  -- Case 1: Press only Button  1
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") == false) then
    Sleep(77)   
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 4)
      Sleep(76) 
    end 
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 6)
      Sleep(62) 
    end
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 5)
      Sleep(84) 
    end

  --Case 2: Press button 1+2
  elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") == false) then
    Sleep(77)   
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 8)
      Sleep(76) 
    end 
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 9)
      Sleep(62) 
    end 
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 0)
      Sleep(84)
    end 
  end
end
```

I want to add one more case when I press RMB of this script:

- When pressed RMB -> press Lshift button
- When release RMB -> press Lshift button again

I added the end of the script as below, it does not work.

```
elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg==2 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")==false) then       
    PressAndReleaseKey("lshift")


elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg==2 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")==false) then
    PressAndReleaseKey("lshift")
```

if I want to add case 3: Press LAlt + LMB, so where do I put IsModifierPressed("lalt") ? I tried as below but failed

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and not IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")) then
    if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then -- 3 = Right Mouse Button (it's the same button as arg==2)
      -- Case 1: Press only LMB
    if IsModifierPressed("lalt") then 
      -- Case 3: Press LAlt+LMB
   else
      -- Case 2: Press RMB+LMB
    end
  elseif ((event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" or event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED") and arg==2 and not IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")) then
    PressKey("lshift") 
    Sleep(50)
    ReleaseKey("lshift") 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Actually the code doesn't do what you say. I'm not familar with the logitech software, but in your case you'll only get into the `elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED"` if key 1 is not pressed (because of the `elseif`). Put the second statement as "normal" if-statement into the other and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and not IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")) then
    if IsModifierPressed("lalt") then 
      -- Case 3: Press LAlt+LMB
    elseif not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then -- 3 = Right Mouse Button (it's the same button as arg==2)
      -- Case 1: Press only LMB
    else
      -- Case 2: Press RMB+LMB
    end
  elseif ((event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" or event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED") and arg==2 and not IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")) then
    PressKey("lshift") 
    Sleep(50)
    ReleaseKey("lshift") 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help in advance: D
I want to add one more case when I press RMB of this script:
- When pressed RMB -> press Lshift button.
- When released RMB -> press Lshift button again.
I added the end of the script as below, it does not work, can you help me?

 elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg==2 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")==false) then  
  PressAndReleaseKey("lshift")


 elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg==2 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")==false) then
  PressAndReleaseKey("lshift")

Comment: one more question pls :)

Comment: @Kel - Updated.

Comment: I have another question, hope you can help me xD [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692011/how-to-reverse-the-movemouserelative-to-exact-first-position-when-releasing-lmb)

Answer (score -1):

You must not have an `end` before an elseif. The elseif serves as the `end` of the last if automatically.

I'm surprised this code even compiles and runs at all, as you mentioned, that the first case does work.

Edit: You also do not need to use parentheses around the condition of an if. Since it is already encapsulated by `if` and `then` it was not necessary for the langugae design to make those mandatory as in other languages.

Comment: It's only bad formatted, the `end` closes the inner `if`.