# How to reverse the MoveMouseRelative to exact first position when releasing LMB

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to make a script for Logitech mouse that:

1. Step 1: When LMB is pressed -> do recoil pattern
2. Step 2: When LMB is released -> MoveMouseRelative to exact position before pressed

So is there any way to try out step 2? This is the script:

```
local Recoil_Pattern = { 
    {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--1st Shot 
    {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--2nd Shot  (hold LMB 100ms)
    {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--3rd Shot (hold LMB 200ms)
    {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--4rd Shot (hold LMB 300ms)
    {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--5rd Shot (hold LMB 400ms)
}
local Shot_Sleep = 100

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
            if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then 
                for i = 1, #Recoil_Pattern do
                    Sleep(10)
                    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                        Sleep(Shot_Sleep)
                        MoveMouseRelative( Recoil_Pattern[i].x, Recoil_Pattern[i].y )       
                    end
                end
            end

        elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
            if not (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then 
                Sleep(10)
                -- How to reverse the MoveMouseRelative to exact first position when releasing LMB
                    -- Ex.
                        -- If press and release LMB -> move mouse relative (0,-10)
                        -- If press and hold LMB for 100ms then release LMB -> move mouse relative (0,-20)
                        -- If press and hold LMB for 400ms then release LMB -> move mouse relative (0,-50)
            end 
        end
    end
```

Edit2:
Great, it works fine with full auto shooting mode, but with semi-auto (I use the "pause" button as the shot button), after if i == 3 then it doesn't fire (it doesn't execute PressAndReleaseKey ( "pause") more). Please help me to make it perfect, I updated the semi-auto firing mode in Edit 2

```
local Recoil_Pattern = {
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--1st Shot
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--2nd Shot (hold LMB 100ms)
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--3rd Shot (hold LMB 200ms)
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--4th Shot (hold LMB 300ms)
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--5th Shot (hold LMB 400ms)
}
local Shot_Sleep = 100

local recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y = 0, 0

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      for i = 1, #Recoil_Pattern do
         Sleep(10)
         if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            PressAndReleaseKey("pause")
            Sleep(Shot_Sleep)
            local dx, dy = Recoil_Pattern[i].x, Recoil_Pattern[i].y
            recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y = recoil_sum_x - dx, recoil_sum_y - dy
            MoveMouseRelative( dx, dy )
            Sleep(Shot_Sleep)
            if i == 3 then
                ctrl_is_down = true
                PressKey("lctrl")
            end
         else
            break
         end
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
        if ctrl_is_down then
                ctrl_is_down = false
                ReleaseKey("lctrl")
            end
      while recoil_sum_x ~= 0 or recoil_sum_y ~= 0 do
         local dx, dy = recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y
         dx = dx > 127 and 127 or dx < -127 and -127 or dx
         dy = dy > 127 and 127 or dy < -127 and -127 or dy
         MoveMouseRelative( dx, dy )
         recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y = recoil_sum_x - dx, recoil_sum_y - dy
         Sleep(10)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Pause` is not a pause (it's special code `Ctrl-Break`).  These two buttons can't be used together.  Choose another key instead of `Pause`.  For example, F13-F24.

Comment: Oh, so that's the reason. I tried another key and it works great, Thank you xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local Recoil_Pattern = {
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--1st Shot
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--2nd Shot  (hold LMB 100ms)
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--3rd Shot (hold LMB 200ms)
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--4rd Shot (hold LMB 300ms)
   {x = 0  ,y = 10 }   ,--5rd Shot (hold LMB 400ms)
}
local Shot_Sleep = 100

local recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y = 0, 0
local ctrl_is_down

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      for i = 1, #Recoil_Pattern do
         Sleep(Shot_Sleep)
         if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            local dx, dy = Recoil_Pattern[i].x, Recoil_Pattern[i].y
            recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y = recoil_sum_x - dx, recoil_sum_y - dy
            MoveMouseRelative( dx, dy )
            if i == 3 then
               ctrl_is_down = true
               PressKey("lctrl")
            end
         else
            break
         end
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
      if ctrl_is_down then
         ctrl_is_down = false
         ReleaseKey("lctrl")
      end
      while recoil_sum_x ~= 0 or recoil_sum_y ~= 0 do
         local dx, dy = recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y
         dx = dx > 127 and 127 or dx < -127 and -127 or dx
         dy = dy > 127 and 127 or dy < -127 and -127 or dy
         MoveMouseRelative( dx, dy )
         recoil_sum_x, recoil_sum_y = recoil_sum_x - dx, recoil_sum_y - dy
         Sleep(10)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: You have always saved my life, thank you for answering me and also helping me improve the script: D. only one thing: somehow when I put the real recoil in, if I hold the mouse to 8th shot, it isn't moved to the first position but continue moving forward (from 1st shot - 7th shot are fine). I have added real recoil in the post, please help me more xD

Comment: The script doesn't know when your pistol produces a shot.  Probably `Shot_Sleep` doesn't correspond to the real fire rate of your weapon.  You can measure the fire rate with a wall clock and then correct the `Shot_Sleep` value.

Comment: I think I found the problem, if the sum of y in `Recoil_Pattern` > 140, it won't work, I also tried it on the desktop just like in-game, is there any way?

Comment: Yes, mouse movement is limited by 127.  Answer updated.

Comment: Got it, you are the best xD

Comment: Sir, I want after release LMB -> press "lshift" for 500 ms. 
I try to add `PressKey("lshift") Sleep(500) ReleaseKey("lshift")` but after release LMB then press LMB again -> the script is not work for 500 ms. It will take 500 ms after release LMB to execute the script again. pls help :D

Comment: Create a macro in LGS (press shift, wait 500ms, release shift).  And insert the line `PlayMacro("YourMacroName")` in the Lua script.

Comment: can we do more: after holding LMB for 300ms (or after firing to the 3rd shot in `Recoil_Pattern`) -> press Ctrl, then when releasing LMB -> release Ctrl

Comment: I mean, if hold LMB for more than 300ms (or shoot to the 3rd shot in `Recoil_Pattern`) -> press Ctrl, then when releasing LMB -> release Ctrl. Otherwise, if after hold LMB for <300ms then release LMB (or after firing to the <3rd shot in `Recoil_Pattern`) -> do not press Ctrl

Comment: Great, it works fine with Full-auto fire mode, but with semi-auto (I use the "pause" button as the shot button), after `if i == 3` then it doesn't fire (it doesn't execute PressAndReleaseKey ( "pause") more)

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly pressed the edit button of your comment: D, please ignore it and please check the post's Edit 2

Comment: Hope you are well, I have another question, hope you can help me again  xD [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399470/how-to-stop-a-repeated-list-of-actions-when-releasing-lmb)