# How to stop a repeated list of actions when releasing LMB

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I have a list of actions as follows:

```
PressAndReleaseKey("f13") -- Action 1
Sleep(200)
PressAndReleaseKey("f13") -- Action 2
Sleep(200)
PressKey("f13") -- Action 3
Sleep(400)
ReleaseKey("f13") -- Action 4
Sleep(200)
```

I want to repeat these actions when pressing LMB and cancel all actions whenever release LMB

Eg:

- if LMB is pressed for **300 ms** and then released => only **Action 1 and Action 2** will be executed (1 time),
- if LMB is pressed for **1800 ms** and then released => **Action 1 and 2** will be executed twice, **Action 3** will be executed once.

So pls help me, this is my script so far:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)

   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1  then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            repeat
                PressAndReleaseKey("f13") -- Action 1
                Sleep(200)
                PressAndReleaseKey("f13") -- Action 2
                Sleep(200)
                PressKey("f13") -- Action 3
                Sleep(400)
                ReleaseKey("f13") -- Action 4
                Sleep(200)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)   
        end     
    end
end
```

---

*(Option 2) In case such `repeat` is not possible => there is another more manual option like `local` that list actions up to 100 times*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cancel any action. You can either execute it or not. Once it is triggered you cannot stop it.

If you want to stop execution after Action 1 and Action 2 you have to check the button state after Action 2 and only execute Action 3 if the button is still pressed. Currently you're checking the button only after all actions have been executed.

Place `if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end` befor any action so it will not be executed if the button is pressed.